# Error when compiling CUDA on Ubuntu 12.04. redefinition of variables

Tags: ubuntu, cuda, ubuntu-12.04, nvcc

I am trying to compile a CUDA program that has worked before on vaious other platforms but I am getting the following error now:

```
In file included from /usr/local/cuda-5.0/bin/crt/link.stub:79:0:
/tmp/tmpxft_00006ff5_00000000-1_align_dlink.reg.c:2:1: error: redefinition of 'const unsigned char def_module_id_str__NV_MODULE_ID []'
/tmp/tmpxft_00006ff5_00000000-1_align_dlink.reg.c:1:1: error: 'const unsigned char def_module_id_str__NV_MODULE_ID [19]' previously defined here
/tmp/tmpxft_00006ff5_00000000-1_align_dlink.reg.c: In function 'void __cudaRegisterLinkedBinary__NV_MODULE_ID(void (*)(void**), void*, void*)':
```

and so on for a number of variables.

I have:

```
$ nvcc -V
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2012 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Fri_Sep_21_17:28:58_PDT_2012
Cuda compilation tools, release 5.0, V0.2.1221
```

gcc version 4.6.3, Tesla M2090 and 64-bit Ubuntu 12.04.

I have built and run the CUDA samples successfully so I think that my environment is set up appropriately.

Comment: I'm sure you probably know this already, but in case not, [cuda 5 is not officially supported on Ubuntu 12.xx](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-toolkit-release-notes/index.html#linux)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The linker in nvcc version 5 works differently than that of version 4. The compiling procedure in my make file is not compatible with version 5. I installed CUDA version 4 and got it all working.